# Stop parent from terminating when child terminates?

Tags: c, linux, clone

I'd like to spawn a process and use stdin/out to communicate to it. That all works, but I noticed when the child terminates via signal the parent does too. Here's an example below. If you uncomment true the program will print "Finish". If you compile and uncomment selfterm then it won't and the parent will terminate with the exit code 137. Why does the parent terminate and how do I prevent it?

main.c

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int doexec(void*) {
    //char*bin = "/usr/bin/true";
    //char*bin = "/tmp/selfterm";
    char*args[] = {bin, 0};
    int err = execv(bin, args);
    return err;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int pid = clone(doexec, malloc(2*1024*1024)+2*1024*1024, CLONE_VFORK|SIGCHLD, 0);
    int status=0;
    wait(&status);
    puts("Finish");
}
```

selfterm.c

```
#include<signal.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { kill(0, 9); }
```

Comment: @Shawn: Check the Linux man page for [`clone(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html).  A signal can be specified in the flags — SIGCHLD is a common option.  See the section "The child termination signal", and the example.  You're right about specifying the top of the stack, not the bottom.

Comment: Pretty sure the stack argument is wrong, too. Stack grows *downward* on Linux so you need a pointer to the *end* of the allocated space, not the beginning.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Really? I looked at the man page first and didn't see anything like that mentioned in the section on the flags argument. Yet it *is* present in the example program at the end. Hmm.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler oops, I'm not sure why it didn't crash when I wrote the stack incorrectly. Real code does indeed point to top

Comment: Ah, found it. In a completely different section of the man page. It's like the author is trying to be confusing...

Comment: @Shawn: yes — `clone()` is a fiendishly complex function.  It takes an hour (or, at least, a long time) to read the man page; it takes a lot longer, and a lot of searching in other man pages, to understand it.  I've not finished the reading yet, let alone the understanding.

Comment: I've never heard that killing a child process kills the parent. Does this only happen when using `clone()` rather than `fork()`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I read it once or twice before. I made sure not to read the outdated one on a certain URL. I didn't seem to notice if it explained how to deal with my problem. I did notice however `wait` supported checking if the process exited with a signal which led me to trying this

Comment: @Barmar I guess you're not on a linux machine to try? Yeah fork has the same issue and uses `SIGCHLD` as well. Removing SIGCHLD from my code doesn't help

Comment: SIGCHLD is the normal signal that's sent when a child exits. But the default disposition is to ignore it, so it shouldn't cause the parent to exit.

Comment: @Barmar I tried switching it up and using SIGALRM in the selfterm code. Same issue, says alarm instead of killed now. It appears without SIGCHLD I still get that signal (using usr bin true) and still terminates using my test binary. If you know how to spawn a binary without having the parent terminate I'll try that method

Comment: Is this specifically an exercise about using `clone()`?  Because my general attitude about `clone()` is: don't use it unless you really, *really* need to do. One of `fork()` or `pthread_create()` is almost always a better choice.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it's not but 1. fork() in c has the same issue. 2. glibc seems to implement fork as `clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `kill()` manual:

> If pid equals 0, then sig is sent to every process in the process group of the calling process.

`kill(0, 9);` terminates all processes in the group including parent process.

You can use `raise()` to send signal to the caller process:

```
raise(SIGKILL);
```

If you want to run child process in process group separated from parent, you can make child process to be a leader of new session with `setsid()`:

```c
int doexec(void *) {
    char *args[] = { "./selfterm", NULL };
    setsid();
    execv(args[0], args);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I may accept this because this does work. What I didnt realize was `*(char*)0 = 1;` will also cause my program to print finish instead of killed. I'm a little curious if a parent can fully insulate itself from the child and not close even if the original kill code above was executed

Comment: @Spill Updated the answer with suggestion.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. If I had more than 100 rep I would start a bounty and give it to you. However, this site usually disallows me from asking questions due to too many people putting my question at -1 or -2 (ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76767797/why-does-map-huge-2mb-fail)